# Twig {% extends %} does not pass variables

Tags: twig, kohana

I use Kohana with twig and extend a template within a template. Param, which is available in my template is not passed to the extended template. How to pass all or at least that value to the extended template?

```
{% extends 'customer/main' %}

{% block content %}
  Will show the content of my_param:{{ my_param }}
{% endblock content %}
```

File: customer/main.html

```
{% extends 'main' %}

{% block middle %}
  Will NOT show the content of my_param:{{ my_param }}
  {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
{% endblock middle %}
```

Comment: Then u are doing something wrong. Code should work as is. [Example](https://twigfiddle.com/dne4w1)

Comment: Yes, I can not even tell what the problem was? Cache? some completely different problem, maybe the one who was sitting i fron of it.  And now? I close this question as not helpful for anybody?

Comment: What exactly do you see on your screen? Could you attach a screenshot? Also are u able to enable the debug mode of `twig`?

Comment: I don't know how `twig` but native kohana view engine don't pass variables to children views. I must use `View::set_global` or add variables in "extend" call

Comment: The problem is/was Cache, the one described here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options and the Server/Cloud I am working on was also caching.